# Socket.io client not connecting to socket.io server flutter on my physical device

Tags: flutter, dart, socket.io, connection, adb

Socket.io client not connecting to socket.io server flutter on my physical device.

*Socket_io_client:Tried every version*

**My Code For Client Side**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:socket_io_client/socket_io_client.dart' as Io;
void main() {
runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
const MyApp({super.key});

// This widget is the root of your application.
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return MaterialApp(

      home:  MyHomePage(),
    );

}
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {

@override
State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

@override
void initState() {
// TODO: implement initState
connect();
super.initState();
}

void connect(){
Io.Socket socket = Io.io('http://192.168.0.197:6969',<String,dynamic>{
'transports':['websocket'],
'autoConnect':false,
});
socket.connect();

socket.onConnect((data) => print("Connection Established"));
socket.onConnectError((data) => print("Error"));
}
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
// This method is rerun every time setState is called, for instance as done
// by the _incrementCounter method above.
//
// The Flutter framework has been optimized to make rerunning build methods
// fast, so that you can just rebuild anything that needs updating rather
// than having to individually change instances of widgets.
return Scaffold(

    );}}
```

**My Code For Server Side**

```
const express = require('express');
const http = require('http');

const { Socket } = require('socket.io');
const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 6969;
var server = http.createServer(app);
var iO = require('socket.io')(server,{

});

app.use(express.json());
app.route('/').get((req,res)=>{
res.json("Hello");
})

iO.on("connection",(socket)=>{
console.log("Connected");
socket.on('sendMsg',(message)=>{
console.log("Your message ",message);

    });

});

server.listen(port,"0.0.0.0",()=>{
console.log('Server Started');
});
```

On Server it shows connected [image]

But on Client it shows error [image]

*-Tried Changing versions of both of the Server and Client [didn't work]*

*-Tried Turning of firewall [didn't work]*

*-Runs on Emulator perfectly.*

Comment: Works perfectly on anemulator? they are on the same network. Try running on your physical device connected to the same network.

Comment: Yeah I did that , that’s is the actual problem it dosen’t work on physical device

Answer (score 0):

Finally fixed it

Solution:
Change the `socket_io_Client` to `1.0.0` and `socket_io_Server` to `2.4.1`